# Getting a resource using another resource's id naming in REST API

Tags: rest

I am defining a REST API and am not sure about naming an endpoint.

I have the following method already

```
GET /users/{user_id}
```

This returns the following:

```
{
    "user_id": "some id",
    "username": "some username (1:1 with user_id)",
    ...
}
```

I want an endpoint to retrieve the resource by `username`, and I am not sure if it should be

```
GET /users/username/{username}
```

or rather

```
GET /usernames/{username}/user
```

or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Usually a resource is uniquely identified by one single identifier. In your case that would be the `user_id`. So your `GET /users/{user_id}` RESTful route makes perfect sense if the `user_id` is what uniquely identifies a user in your system.

On the other hand if you want to be searching users by some other criteria (like a `username`) you could just use query string parameters:

```
GET /users?username=foo_bar
```

which will obviously return an array of users whose username matches this criteria and if in your case the username is unique this array will always contain at most one element:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 123,
        "username": "foo_bar"
    }
]
```

On the other hand if you decide that `user_id` is some internal system identifier for the `user` resource in your system (for example that could be the primary key in your SQL database) and you want to expose some friendlier unique id in your RESTful facade to the users, then you might consider using `GET /users/{username}`. Of course in this case you should very well define what a `username` is and what are the allowed characters for it because things could quickly turn into a nightmare if you allow some special characters in a username. Here's a [`good read`](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding) on this topic that I very strongly encourage you to go through and very well understand what are the allowed characters in the path segment of an URL.

Comment: Good read: https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/lunatech%5Ewhat-every-webdev-must-know-about-url-encoding/

Answer (score 0):

I'd just add a query paramter

```
GET /users?username=john
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving users by username does not really fit in the REST scheme, so I would either go with the already proposed solution `/users?name=....` or [possibly more comprehensive] `/users/<username>`. I would use the latter only if the usernames do not need to be URI-encoded (in the best case - do not contain chars other than alpha-numeric and underscore)