# Extracting the id of a name ressource from a REST API

Tags: rest

I am trying to get the id of the "Bold of Damask" item from the https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items API http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/items.

I tried to acces using [https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items?name="Bolt of Damask"](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items?name=%22Bolt%20of%20Damask%22) but in vain.

Any Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the root endpoint (/v2/items) is accessed without specifying an id,
>   a list of all ids is returned. When multiple ids are requested using
>   the ids parameter, a list of response objects is returned.

There seems to be no "search" for this API, so you have to find a different way to discover the id.

Maybe you can try matching the wiki page (there is the id on some links on the right), or just loop all the items once and save it somewhere.

https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bolt_of_Damask

https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/46741

But your best choice is to **use another API**:

http://api.gw2tp.com/1/bulk/items-names.json

Here you can see all the id with their names, and I bet you will find something useful. :)

https://www.gw2tp.com/api

Comment: Thanks, but how did you found the id ?

Comment: I've edited the answer, the GW2TP apis seems more complete. Btw in the links on the right of the wiki page there are some links pointing to the item page, with its id.

Comment: thanks, but is there a more dynamic solution ? I read this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244627/getting-a-resource-using-another-resources-id-naming-in-rest-api] but the proposed solution don't work in my case

Comment: This strictly depends on the APIs specification. I guess that since these items are pretty "stable" you can assume that they will not change a lot, and that's why they are using something static like a text file. You can probably just download the file once and update it once in a while.